# JQuery: What's the difference between referencing an element using #[objectId] or [id=objectId]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Can anybody tell me what's the difference between referencing an element using 
`#[objectId]` or `[id=objectId]`?

Comment: There is no difference (other than speed). They return the same thing.

Comment: 1. performance, 2. readability.

Comment: I have experience some problems in some situations using #objectID...

Comment: If you have problem with #object it's because you have more than 1 element with that id, which is invalid HTML

Comment: @user3301806 What kind of problem ? And what kind of id ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first one is very fast, as jQuery internally uses `getElementById` when it recognizes the pattern (using a regular expression).

The second one asks jQuery to iterate over all objects having an id. It's very slow. jQuery doesn't even stop iterating when it find one match in that case.

The only legitimate reason to use a `[id...` selector is when you don't just search by an exact id, for example you might want to search all elements whose id starts with `"something"` using `$('[id^=something]')`.

Assuming you have a valid HTML ([no reused id](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)) and a valid id, you can still have problems with `$('#'+someId)` (for example when your id contains a quote, or anything that breaks Sizzle's pattern recognition system). In that case, use `$(document.getElementById(someId))`.

---

Following your comment : Yes, a `"@"` in an ID makes it impossible for Sizzle (jQuery's selector engine) to understand your selector. Sizzle uses the following regex :

```
rquickExpr = /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/,
```

and `/^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*|#([\w-]*))$/.test('#som@thing')` returns `false`.

Comment: dystroy: Your last paragraph nail it! I have @ in my Id. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses!